# Most concise code for tangent and normal line of implicit algebraic curve

Tags: geometry, algebraic-manipulation

Can you make the code for tangent line and normal line of implicit algebraic curve `cu` more concise than mine?

The code for tangent line at `{x,y}={8,7}` is:

```
D[cu, {{x, y}}] . {a - x, b - y} /. {x -> 8, y -> 7} /. {a -> x, b -> y} // Expand
```

The code for normal line at `{x,y}={8,7}` is:

```
D[cu, {{y, x}}] . {a - x, -b + y} /. {x -> 8, y -> 7} /. {a -> x, b -> y} // Expand
```

What I do not like about my code is that it uses two `Rule`'s and two temporary and meaningless variables `a, b`.

```
cu = 3 x^2 + 5 y^2 - 7 x y + 2 x - 9 y + 2;
cu == 0 /. {x -> 8, y -> 7}
D[cu, {{x, y}}] . {a - x, b - y} /. {x -> 8, y -> 7} /. {a -> x, 
   b -> y} // Expand
D[cu, {{y, x}}] . {a - x, -b + y} /. {x -> 8, y -> 7} /. {a -> x, 
   b -> y} // Expand
ContourPlot[{cu == 0, %% == 0, % == 0}, {x, -2, 10}, {y, 0, 8}, 
 Epilog -> {Point[{8, 7}]}, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
Clear[cu]

(* True *)

(* -43 + x + 5 y *)

(* -33 + 5 x - y *)
```

[image]

Comment: `{x,y}` is on the curve  `cu` and `{X,Y}` is on the tangen line. `D[cu, {{x, y}}] . ({X, Y} - {x, y}) /. {x -> 8, y -> 7} // Expand`

Comment: It is the same as mine you just renamed variables and the result tangent is in `X, Y` which you have to replace by another rule to have it in desired `x, y` variables.

Comment: For example, I always use `Y==((f[x]-f[x0])/(x-x0))*(X-x0)+f[x0]` to express a  line which passes through the point `{x0,f[x0]}` and `{x,f[x]}`. `{x,y}` is on the curve `{x,f[x]}` and  `{X,Y}` is on the line.

Answer (score 6):

- For the curve `f[x,y]==0`, we use

```
grad = Through@*Apply[{Derivative[1, 0][f], Derivative[0, 1][f]}];
```

to define a `Grad` operator to calculus the normal of implicit curve `f[x,y]==0` on the point `pt={a,b}={8,7}`.

```
Clear["Global`*"];
f[x_, y_] := 3 x^2 + 5 y^2 - 7 x y + 2 x - 9 y + 2;
rotation = RotationTransform[π/2];
grad = Through@*Apply[{Derivative[1, 0][f], Derivative[0, 1][f]}];
pt = {8, 7};

ContourPlot[{f[x, y] == 0, grad@{a, b} . {x - a, y - b} == 0, 
    rotation@grad@{a, b} . {x - a, y - b} == 0} /. 
   Thread[{a, b} -> pt] // Evaluate, {x, -2, 10}, {y, 0, 8}, 
 Epilog -> {Point[pt]}, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image]

- animation.

```
plot = ContourPlot[f[x, y] == 0, {x, -2, 10}, {y, 0, 8}];
pts = Cases[plot, GraphicsComplex[pts_, data__] :> pts, -1] // First;
data = Table[
   ContourPlot[{f[x, y] == 0, grad@pt . ({x, y} - pt) == 0, 
      rotation@grad@pt . ({x, y} - pt) == 0} // Evaluate, {x, -2, 
     10}, {y, 0, 8}, Epilog -> {Point[pt]}, 
    AspectRatio -> Automatic], {pt, pts}];
ani = ListAnimate[data]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can use[`Dt`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dt.html). For example for curve `cu`:

```
cu = 3 x^2 + 5 y^2 - 7 x y + 2 x - 9 y + 2;
```

you can do:

```
tn[f_, p_] := Module[{td = Dt[f], t, n, ex1, ex2},
  t = td /. {Dt[x] -> {1, 0}, Dt[y] -> {0, 1}};
  n = td /. {Dt[x] -> {0, 1}, Dt[y] -> {-1, 0}};
  ex1 = (t /. Thread[{x, y} -> p]) . ({x, y} - p);
  ex2 = (n /. Thread[{x, y} -> p]) . ({x, y} - p);
  Column[{ContourPlot[{f == 0, ex1 == 0, ex2 == 0}, {x, -2, 
      10}, {y, -2, 10}, Epilog -> {Red, Point[p]}],
    Grid[{{"curve", f == 0}, {StringForm["tangent at ``", p], 
       ex1 == 0},
      {StringForm["normal at ``", p], ex2 == 0}}, Alignment -> Left, 
     Frame -> All, ItemSize -> 30]
    }, Frame -> All]]
```

Note the first 4 lines are relevant. The rest is window dressing for visualization.

Using @cvgmt `pts`: `pts = Cases[ContourPlot[cu == 0, {x, -2, 10}, {y, -2, 10}],  GraphicsComplex[pts_, data__] :> pts, -1] // First;`

and exporting as animated gif:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

```
{$tF, $nF} = Table[With[{i = i}, 
  Module[{v = Variables[#]}, Dot[i @ Grad[#, v] /. Thread[v -> #2], v - #2]] &],
 {i, {Identity, Cross}}];
```

***Examples:***

```
cu = 2 + 2 x + 3 x^2 - 9 y - 7 x y + 5 y^2;

pt = {8, 7};

ContourPlot[Evaluate @ {cu == 0, $tF[cu, pt] == 0, $nF[cu, pt]}, 
 {x, -2, 10}, {y, -2, 10}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-2, 10}, {-2, 10}}, 
 Epilog -> {Red  , PointSize @ Large, Point @ pt}]
```

[image]

```
cP[pt_] := ContourPlot[
  Evaluate @ {cu == 0, tLF[cu, pt] == 0, nLF[cu, pt]}, 
  {x, -2, 10}, {y, -2, 10}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-2, 10}, {-2, 10}}, 
  Epilog -> {Red  , PointSize@Large, Point@pt}];

coords = First @ Cases[ContourPlot[cu == 0, {x, -2, 10}, {y, -2, 10}], 
   GraphicsComplex[c_, ___] :> c, All];

frames = cP /@ coords;

Export["tnframes.gif", frames[[;; ;; 2]], DisplayAllSteps -> True]
```

[image]

```
cu2 = x^4 - 2 x^2 + y^4 - 2 y^2;

SeedRandom[1];
pts = RandomSample[{x, y} /. FindInstance[cu2 == 0, {x, y}, Reals, 20], 3];

ContourPlot[Evaluate @ 
    {cu2 == 0, 
     $tL[cu2, pts[[1]]] == 0, $nL[cu2, pts[[1]]] == 0, 
     $tL[cu2, pts[[2]]] == 0, $nL[cu2, pts[[2]]] == 0,
     $tL[cu2, pts[[3]]] == 0, $nL[cu2, pts[[3]]] == 0},
   {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
  Epilog -> {Red  , PointSize@Large, Point /@ pts}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

One alternative:

```
curve = 3 x^2 + 5 y^2 - 7 x y + 2 x - 9 y + 2; {$x, $y} = {8, 7};
slope = D[curve, x]/D[curve, y] /. {x -> $x, y -> $y};
{tangent, orthogonal} =  (y - $y) + # (x - $x) slope^# & /@ {1, -1};

ContourPlot[{curve == 0, tangent == 0, orthogonal == 0}
   , {x,-10,10}, {y, -10, 10}
   , PlotLegends -> {"Curve", "Tangent", "Orthogonal"}
   , Epilog -> {Red, PointSize -> Medium, Point[{$x, $y}]}
, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

A concise form of the tangent line can be obtained with homogeneous coordinates (HC). In HC the ellipse is implicitly written:

```
m = {{2, 1, -9/2}, {1, 3, -7/2}, {-9/2, -7/2, 5}};
p = {1, x, y};
p.m.p==0

2 + 2 x + 3 x^2 - 9 y - 7 x y + 5 y^2 ==0
```

This is the same formula as your cu==0

Now the formula for the tangent at {8,7} can be written very simply:

```
p0={1,8,7};
p0.m.p == 0
```

[image]

As this are homogeneous coordinates, this is the same line as:

```
-43 + x + 5 y == 0
```

The normal to a line given by: {a0,a1,a2} through the point {1,b1,b2} on a is:

```
 {-a1 b2+a2 b1,- a2,a1}
```

and the equation of this line:

```
-a1 b2+a2 b1 - a2 x + a1 y ==0
```

Therefore for your case:

{-1  7 + 5 8, -5, 1} -> {3,-5,1}

resulting in the normal equation:

```
33 - 5 x + y == 0
```